# ssisUnit & SSIS package

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

In our project we use SSIS and we test it. Therefor, we have many test for SSIS packages.
However, something wrong with the last one . When package starts on the Build Machine (TeamCity) with ssisUnit(C#) it inserts to `sysssislog` table the following error:

`The result of the expression "[Some Expression]" on property "SqlStatementSource" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.`

This error is repeated for all tasks that have expression. However, other tests works as well. 
Another strange thing that is if I run it from local computer or from Job in the same machine or manually- it works as well!

- We use BIDS 2008 for package creation
- Package has been started from the file system during the test
- OS: Windows 8
- SQL server: 2008R2

---

I have also investigated this problem with google.

1. Set `DelayValidation=true`  - it does not help
2. Provide a default valid value for property with expression - it also does not help

---

I see that someone have already had such problem (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339631/ssis-error-the-result-of-the-expression-userfilename-cannot-be-writ)) but nobody helps

Comment: Not enough detail to diagnose the problem. How is the expression built on the component? What is the expression? If you create the expression on a Variable and then assign the Variable into the SqlStatementSource, do you get the same result?

Comment: Your statement is structurally sound and has default values that result in successful validation, but when it executes the expression evaluates to something invalid.  It's likely related to permissions -- does your expression rely on environment dependent information that might not be available to the executing account?

Comment: Full error looks like: `The result of the expression ""delete top(" + (DT_STR, 100, 1251)@[User::CountRecords]  + ") from SPI 
output P.*
from SI_PhoneID SPI join Phone P on P.PhoneID = SPI.PhoneID"" on property "SqlStatementSource" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.
`

Comment: "If you create the expression on a Variable and then assign the Variable into the SqlStatementSource, do you get the same result?" - thanks for that. It is worth a try